# Change styleName to className in JSX/TSX files with Emmet

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx, emmet

In June 2023 [update](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_80#_improved-emmet-support-for-css-modules-in-jsxtsx) of VS Code. Developers add possibility to customize CSS modules in JSX/TSX files.

But now it doesn`t work.
Here my settings

```
  "emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
    "jsx, tsx": {
      "markup.attributes": {
        "class*": "className"
      }
    }
  },
```

Also I used custom file with snippets for Emmet. Try add this rule there and try to disable snippet file. It doesn`t help

UPD. Add link the VS Code Update

Comment: why post an image instead of a link to the release web page section tag

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_80#_improved-emmet-support-for-css-modules-in-jsxtsx